# I have installed Android Studio but powershell can't find Gradle and Java

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

[enter image description here][1]I am new to app development. I have recently installed Android Studio.
When I try to run my app it shows error 1. I have tried "gradle --version" and
"java --version" commands but powershell does not recognize gradle and java. Should I install gradle and separately? Because I can't find their exe files in the android studio installation folder.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

if `java --version` is not working then that means java is not in path find the JDK in your file structure and add it to your path (must look something like this `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.8\bin`) then create a new environment variable `JAVA_HOME` and and add path as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.8` (depends on your PC and where you installed it) after this uninstall and reinstall android studio also you cant just access gradel with command line its not installed in you PC also its not required there is a gradel file and gradel is inbuilt in android studio, just add java to path and reinstall android studio

Comment: I have never installed Java. I thought it would come with Android Studio.

Comment: @UsamaKhalid java and gradel do come with android studio but they are just available for use with android studio they are not added to the path so you can't use them with power shell if you want to use them with PowerShell then you have to install them seperately

Comment: I have just created an app that will just print "Hello World" and I am trying to run it in Android Studio. and still getting this error.

Comment: uninstall and reinstall and this time use a proper network connection, when you start android studio it will ask for some stuff to download let it do that then make an empty project and wait for the gradel to be built then you can run the app, if the app is not running the installation is faulty so you need to reinstall